# How to specify database name for particular Class or entity in EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, database-design, architecture, entity-framework-4.1

We are using two database in that i need to inherit this model or entity table alone. For this how to specify database name for particular class or entity table in entity-frame work. It is possible?

```
Database Name: "Test1"

public class User : BaseEntity
{        
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

**now how to set this model as navigation property in another model. like,**

```
Database Name: "Test2"

public class Test: BaseEntity
{
  public int UserId { get; set; }

  public virtual User User { get; set; }
}

public class BaseEntity
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Your question is somewhat confusing. Maybe you should try to show, in pseudo-code perhaps, what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @steen: now i edited the question u can see it.

Comment: That's not inheritance, that's a navigation property. What are you trying to accomplish by doing this, and what is your problem? =)

Comment: @steen: i need to get that User object automatically. it is possible?

Comment: Is the data represented by the User object stored in a different database than, in this case, Test?

Comment: yes. user table is in another database i need to get that user object.

Comment: Then no, it can't be done automatically. You could set up a linked server in the SQL database, and create a view that points to your User table. For example.

Comment: Actually. This answer might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036357/making-an-entity-framework-model-span-multiple-databases

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13995/discussion-between-thulasiram-and-j-steen)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity Framework `DbContext` **could handle one Database**.
Then you should have two `DbContext`'s for your two Databases.

---

***Update :***

I advice you not to do that. in another words you **your Database and your Model should be in harmony** "*I love this word* :)"

And anything beyond that I suppose it should be in Service class "Layer".

So in your example you suppose to have a `UserService` class the get your User and don't do this logic in the `Test` class.

One another thing to notice: If your model connected together like this way then you should have just one Database.

Comment: now how to inherit this model in another model. like,
public virtual User User { get; set; }

Answer (score 0):

If you want to `inherit` your class from the `User` class, this is how it is

```
public class Test: User 
{
   public int UserId { get; set; } 
}
```

Now `Test` class will have all the properties of the base class (`User`) along with it's own property `UserId`