# Entity Framework - how to manage tables in different databases but on the same server?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, database-design

I am using SQL Server 2008.

It seems as though in EF I need a different entity context for each database. Joining tables between databases means having to allow for this which is inconvenient and makes it more likely that I would simply put everything in one database.

Am I missing something? Surely EF can work better than this?

Comment: AFAIK, it's not generally a good idea to join tables in separate databases, which is why EF doesn't support it.

Comment: The implication of that is that you should only have 1 database. That does not seem right to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could map your entities to a view that returns joined tables, so your EF model doesn't know about all this technical DB stuff.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's properly supported, but [this guy has managed to get it to work](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/22/tricking-ef-to-span-multiple-databases/).

Basically, she set up Synonyms for the databases, and hacked the edmx file.

Comment: That's living dangerously! :)

Comment: Indeed, I wouldn't really recommend it but it has been done! :)

Comment: I'm "this guy", and it wasn't really a hack :) I simply merged two edmx files, so the final copy contained the definitions for both databases, and setup Synonyms on the first database that pointed to the 2nd database's objects. I actually have a question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6036357/302677) asking if this is a bad idea or not, and the answer I got was from someone I trust in the EF field :)

Comment: Thanks for the comment! :) What do you think about ken2k's alternative?

Comment: @JoeR I'm a lazy person, and it seemed like too much work ;) I was working with a fairly large database at the time, and creating updatable Views for every database table, along with indexes, keys, links, etc and finding/updating the Defining Query in the edmx seemed like a huge hassle.

Comment: Although I would definitely use a simple View like ken2k suggested if I only wanted to read the data, or I'd use Stored Procedures if I only had a small number of insert/update/delete statements I wanted to run on the 2nd database.