# add foreign key that points to table in external database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mapping

I have database ObjectTypes with the (id,...).
I want in my model (EF 4) to add refference from my database in some table foreign key to refference to objectTypes.dbo.ObjectTypes field. How can I do that?

```
 public class KOATUUContext : DbContext
{
    static KOATUUContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<KOATUUContext>(null);
    }

    public KOATUUContext()
        : base("KOATUU")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<KOATUU> KOATUUs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Region> Regions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TerType> TerTypes { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new KOATUUMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new RegionMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new TerTypeMap());
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot. Different Databases require different `DbContext` instances. EF can only query against one single instance.

Comment: I have another DbContext. But I cannot specify in one context to refference table in another

Comment: I think you can join two Lists using Linq?

Comment: The problem is that when model is created, it wants foreign key from first context

Comment: However i specified connection string in app.config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought this was not possible as well, but this post seems to discuss the same problem with a working solution:

[Making an Entity Framework Model span multiple databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036357/making-an-entity-framework-model-span-multiple-databases)

Comment: Note: follow the poster's link to the detailed write-up on her approach.