# Entity framework foregin key in another database

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

So i like MVC and EF6 but I keep coming across fundamental problems with the way it / I work.

I have an app ( a very simple one) in there one of my tables references a field in another database, how would EF handle this , it seems to get very complicated whereas in the past it would have been a simple ADO.NET call to a stored procedure or something ( I am aware I can use SP's with EF, but really, what's the point , may as well just use ADO.NET again), example model below:

```
 [Table("Target")]
public partial class Target
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int SomeForeignKeyInMyDbID { get; set; }

    public Guid? FOREGINKEYINANOTHERDB { get; set; }
}
```

when I scaffold views based of this it automatically creates the drop down menus etc really well but it (obviously) cannot pickup the reference to the foreign key in another field, as I want to store the ID of the foreign key in the database but get the value of it for drop downs etc, I store the ID instead of the value for reporting reasons.

I thought that I would just be able to get a context to my other db, grab the values I need and bind them to the drop down list but the model structure is so tightly defined that I face hurdle after hurdle on this.

I read somewhere that my best option may be to use SP's for CRUD operations and then perform a LINQ to EF query fro the index view and do a join on foreginkeyfromanotherdb field.

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making an Entity Framework Model span multiple databases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036357/making-an-entity-framework-model-span-multiple-databases)

Comment: I am using code first from existing database in EF 6.1

Comment: So no that dies not address my problem

Comment: Anyone able to help?